# htaccess: rewriting with index parameter doesn't work properly

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, include

Alright, so I'm really struggling right now, I've tried everything, read articles and tutorials but I still don't know why this doesn't work.

I've got an **index.php** file:

```
echo "some test";
if(isset($para)) {
    include $para . '.php';
} else {
    echo "there's no parameter";
}
```

So if the user views the page with the parameter 'home' (http://mypage.com/test/index.php?para=home), he'll get the correct page. That does work.

**.htaccess**:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mypage.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mypage.com/test/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteBase /test/
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ index.php?para=$1
```

But when I try to navigate using the rewritten link (http://mypage.com/test/home), the browser only outputs the **included file** and it completely ignores the **index.php** and its content.

Is there something wrong with my htaccess file? Or do I need to change some server configuration? Because I had a different htaccess file on a different webserver and it worked without any issues. But it didn't work on the webserver I'm using right now (sadly, I only have access to the htdocs folder).

**EDIT:** Just checked phpinfo, the page is running on PHP 5.3.28 on apache2.

## Solved!

Problem solved. Adding 'Options -Multiviews' fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The hint here is:

> The browser only outputs the included file and it completely ignores
>   the index.php and its content.

Try disabling mod_negotiation (Options -Multiviews) in the context where you want to do this remapping with mod_rewrite and within your script.

mod_negotiation is the most common reason "other" rewriting seems to be happening on your resources.

Comment: Yep, it works now! I'll add the current .htaccess file to my post. Thanks!